# gnome-screenshot - capture area screenshot after a delay?

Tags: gnome3

I found this extremely weird:

```
$ gnome-screenshot -d 5 -a -c
Conflicting options: --area and --delay should not be used at the same time.
```

Why shouldn't area and delay not be used at the same time? What is the problem?

Basically, I want to take a screenshot that includes say a right-click context menu - gnome-screenshot usually cancels these before taking a screenshot (I'm trying to hold back my cynicism, but I can't - so thank you for this "feature", that is very useful!).

So I have to use a delay if I want to capture a right-click context menu or something - but if I cannot capture an area, that means I have to waste up to a minute more to open the screenshot in an application, crop, save - EDIT: and obviously, I mention this because I do **not** want to waste extra time to perform steps manually, if they can be performed automatically (and in this case, they - in principle - can).

Can I somehow persuade gnome-screenshot to allow both area and delay? Lacking that, is there a Linux application that can?

Comment: Use window and delay, then edit the image?

Comment: Thanks, @XTian - but did I not already write "... *that means I have to waste up to a minute more to open the screenshot in an application, crop, save*"? Just to clarify, I mentioned that because I want to avoid wasting up to a minute more than I need to.